# jQuery toggle only works first time

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle() button that I'm trying to get to show a plus/minus image. The only time it actually works is on the first click.

**My code:**

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".mainlist").slideToggle(function () {
        $('span.minus').html('<img src="images/plus.png">');
        },function() {
        $('span.minus').html('<img src="images/minus.png">');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="minus"><img src="images/minus.png"></span>
```

I'm using the `on` because the content inside of #xmlDiv is populated after page load.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show `HTML` also or reproduce your problem with `codepen` or `jsfiddel` to understand it better.

Comment: `slideToggle()` first parameter should be duration in milliseconds - not a function.

Comment: Put some `console.log()` calls in the two functions to make sure that they are being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) can have only one callback which will call after completion, not multiple callback like `hover` event.

```
.slideToggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

Consider following code having 2 parameter:

- duration
- Callback

---

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if($('span.minus img').attrib('src') == 'images/plus.png')
            $('span.minus img').attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        else
            $('span.minus img').attr("src", "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operator `?` `:` to  to show a plus/minus image. My solution is following

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".mainlist").slideToggle(function () {
        $('span.minus').html($('span.minus').html('<img src="images/plus.png">') == '<img src="images/plus.png">' ? '<img src="images/minus.png">' : '<img src="images/plus.png">');
    });
});
```